# how to display multiple images from database to blade view, by Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a multiple images in "Images" column in DB, and I need to display all Images in:

```
@foreach(explode(',', $posts->images) as $images)
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <a href="{{ URL::to('img/offers/'.$images)}}"
       class="portfolio-box">
        <img src="{{ URL::to('img/offers/'.$images)}}"
             class="img-responsive" alt="--">
        <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"
                  style="font-size: 80px"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div> 
@endforeach
```

but it not working because link show like:

```
http://localhost:8000/img/offers/["149939592986Dynamic-Web.png"
```

and next image show like:

```
http://localhost:8000/img/offers/"149938949479Static-Web.png"]
```

now, what i do to display all images ?

my column in BD show like an array:

```
["149938949418Dynamic-Web.png","149938949479Static-Web.png"]
```

thank you.

Comment: This is json. Learn what is it and how to work with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php

Comment: have you tried: `@foreach(json_decode($posts->images, true) as $images)`

Comment: @Chris thank you very much, i have one more question, what if i want to display only first image ?

Comment: @MohämmädHämdy `json_decode($posts->images, true)[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your example does not work is because you are exploding a json string. What you will have to do is to simple decode it properly, like this:

```
@foreach(json_decode($posts->images, true) as $images)
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <a href="{{ URL::to('img/offers/'.$images)}}"
       class="portfolio-box">
        <img src="{{ URL::to('img/offers/'.$images)}}"
             class="img-responsive" alt="--">
        <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"
                  style="font-size: 80px"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div> 
@endforeach
```

This will loop through all your images and display the correct strings like:

```
http://localhost:8000/img/offers/149939592986Dynamic-Web.png
```

Comment: thank you very much, i have one more question, what if i want to display only first image ?

Comment: If you want to display first image then you can use: `json_decode($posts->images, true)[0]` it should return the first index of the converted array

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi How it is work like here ?! it's not working with me !! @ foreach($posts as $post) <img src="{{ URL::to('img/offers/'.$post->images)}}"><h3>{{$post->title}}</h3> @ endforeach

Comment: you don't need `foreach` loop if you need the first `json_decode($posts->images, true)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You have `json` encoded data so you have to decode. So,
you can use `json_decode()` to extract array of image file names as:

```
 $images = json_decode($posts->images,true);
```

After this you can use simple `for` loop to show all images,

```
 @foreach($images as $image)
     <div>
          <--! Write code to display image -->
     </div>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: thank you very much, i have one more question, what if i want to display only first image ?

Comment: Simply use `{{ $images[0] }}` as in other array